# Python - How to judge if input variable is duplicated in a function or not?

Tags: python, function, class

I've just get to know about Class and User-Defined-Function in Python and currently practicing with them.

Sometimes I got really confused whether an inputted **variable or instance attribute** is directly used or been copied as a local variable that only works during the call of function.

For example:

```
class test1(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class test2(object):
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.a = test.a
        self.add_d()
    def add_d(self):
        self.a += 'd'
        print self.a

class test3(object):
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.fc = test
        self.add_d()
    def add_d(self):
        self.fc.a += 'd'
        print self.fc.a
```

And:

```
In [36]: t = test1('abc')
In [37]: test2(t)
abcd
Out[37]: <__main__.test2 at 0xce5bcf98>
In [38]: t.a
Out[38]: 'abc'
```

It **didn't change** attribute "a" of instance "t" from class test1.

```
In [39]: test3(t)
abcd
Out[39]: <__main__.test3 at 0xfc3c9e8>
In [40]: t.a
Out[40]: 'abcd'
```

It **changed** attribute "a" of instance "t" from class test1.

Usually, I used functions for several scenario:

1. Aim to alter (mutate) the input variables from calling a function.
2. The return value is the only thing desired from the function call, and inputted variables should be unchanged.
3. Passing an Axes of matplotlib and arrange plotting commands in the function. (This would always work, never went wrong.)

Things would be pretty troublesome if I made unwanted changes to raw data and vice versa. So what is the basic concept here? Also, is there any habits that we should develop to prevent this kind of mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are asking why was the `test1` instance modified in the second example but not modified in the first?

In the first one after:

```
self.a = test.a
```

`self.a` refers to `test.a` which is the same *immutable* string object. Now when:

```
self.a += 'd'
```

executes it *rebinds* the value of the expression `self.a + d` to `self.a`, i.e. a new string object is created. Because strings are immutable the original can not be altered, so a new one must be created. At this point the attribute `a` in the `test2` object refers to a *different* object than the `a` attribute in the `test1` object, which remains unchanged.

In the second example after

```
self.fc = test
```

`self.fc` refers to the object `test` which is the *same* object that the variable `t` refers to. In terms of variable references this is the same as the first case, however, the difference is that this object is mutable so when

```
self.fc.a += 'd'
```

executes a new string is created and bound to the `a` attribute of the object - but `self.fc` still refers to the same object. Hence `t.a` is changed.

I've tried to explain this in terms of your example. The crucial point is that Python variables refer to objects, and there can be multiple references to the same object. Changes to the object can be made via any of the referring variables, and that change will be visible regardless of which variable is used to view it. Copies of objects are not made during assignment, however, the reference can be changed if a new object is created in order to preserve the immutability of certain objects.

I recommend that you give this a read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: I see, so the key point is about if an object is immutable or not... I do thought of Python in C++ way, and that cause the problem. Thank you so much for the answer and the article, it's very helpful and enlightening,